# volume of a triangular pyramid

Tags: volume

A point $M_0$ with positive coordinates $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$, $x_0>0$, $y_0>0$, $z_0>0$ is given.
A plane is drawn through this point.
Find the minimal possible volume of a triangular pyramid whose
faces lie in the plane mentioned above and in the coordinate planes.

Answer (score 2):

Let the plane equation $\frac{x}{a}+\frac{y}{b}+\frac{z}{c}=1$ then the volume is $\frac{1}{6}abc$, so (Lagrangian multipliers, $abc\to\min$).
$$\begin{cases}
bc-\lambda\frac{x_0}{a^2}=0\\
ac-\lambda\frac{y_0}{b^2}=0\\
ab-\lambda\frac{y_0}{c^2}=0\\
\frac{x_0}{a}+\frac{y_0}{b}+\frac{z_0}{c}=1
\end{cases}$$
$$\begin{cases}
abc-\lambda\frac{x_0}{a}=0\\
abc-\lambda\frac{y_0}{b}=0\\
abc-\lambda\frac{y_0}{c}=0\\
\frac{x_0}{a}+\frac{y_0}{b}+\frac{z_0}{c}=1
\end{cases}$$
Since $\frac{x_0}{a}=\frac{y_0}{b}=\frac{y_0}{c}$ so these three $=\frac{1}{3}$,
$a=3x_0$, $b=3y_0$, $c=3z_0$, $V=\frac{27}{6}x_0y_0z_0$.